# C - Left Shift or Add to Itself (Speed)

Tags: c

Which is executes faster?

1:

```
n = n << 1;
```

2:

```
n = n + n;
```

Comment: On what machine? With what compiler? What is the surrounding code? The answer depends on all of these things and more. Depending on the type and value of `n`, these aren't necessarily even the same operation anyway.

Comment: "Pre-optimization is the root of all evil." Use the one the most apropos to what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, `<<` *can be* faster for signed types because it's less-strictly defined. `n+n` is defined whenever it doesn't overflow, but `n<<1` is defined only when `n` is non-negative and the result does not overflow.

In reality, the compiler will generate the exact same machine code for both.

Answer (score 6):

Any good compiler will end up making them both the same, so I can't imagine it matters.