# What is an alternative to divide by 2

Tags: java, c++

this is a question which needs to be answer for a job interview, I only know how to do the following:

```
int x = y/2;
```

is there any alternatives ?

Comment: Shifting bits...  Really, you should already know this, if you're interviewing for a job.

Comment: can you explain a little more on this ?

Comment: Even a cursory google search should give you [Division by two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_two), and very little more work will give you language specific implementations.

Comment: Trick question! You need to know the type of `y` :).

Comment: @dlf Good point, making bit shifting questionable!

Comment: Relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681375/which-is-better-option-to-use-for-dividing-an-integer-number-by-2 By the way, how I found that was by Googling "divide number by two C++"

Answer (score 11):

Shift right by 1 bit:

```
int x = y >> 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to let the interviewer know that you're up for the fun:

```
int x = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < y; i += 2)
{
    x++;
}
```

Of course, you'll need to do some additional stuff for a negative number, but you get the drill ;)

Answer (score 1):

`a << 1` is the same as `a * 2`. And `a >> 1` is the same as `a/2`

Comment: Not if `a` is negative (assuming C++).

Comment: The unsigned right shift operator ">>>" shifts a zero into the leftmost position, while the leftmost position after ">>" depends on sign extension.

Answer (score 1):

Well as Drakosha said shifting right by 1 :

```
int x = y >> 1;
```

or

multiply by 0.5:

```
int x = (int)(y * 0.5);
```

or

subtract by the value multiplied by 0.5:

```
int x = (int)(y - (y * 0.5));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use shifting of bits you could even keep on subtracting the number by 2 till you get the remainder less than 2. Keep a count of how many times you subtracted. Plain maths.

Answer (score 0):

As said, you also could shift the number bitwise. The operator is >> or <<.
Look this example, should make everything clear:

```
int x = 16;
x = x >> 1;
System.out.println(x); // prints 8
```