# Why does "n&1 == 0" always return false?

Tags: c++, c, c++11

Why does the expression `n&1 == 0` always return `false`, where `n` is an integer?

I want to use bitwise operation to determine whether `n` is even. However, it always return false. (The clion also prompted me that it always returns `false`).

What's more, it works when I use `n&1 != 0` to determine whether `n` is odd.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: If `(n & 1) == false` then it's even number and odd otherwise. In g++, compile with `-Wall` option so that it will give you warning for `n & 1 == 0` for putting braces around.

Comment: the way you have it looks like `n&(1==0)` so since `1==0` is always 0 we get `n&0` which is always 0

Comment: This has no relation to IDE whatsoever. It's because of the C standard. To determine if a number is odd, just `if (n & 1)` is enough. But better use [`n % 2 == 1`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10681375/995714)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Its because of the operator precedence.

`==` has higher precedence than the `&` operator, so `1 == 0` gets evaluated first to 0. Then the bit wise AND is performed which ultimately returns false.