# Decimal number to 32 bit binary

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

```
int main()
{
    unsigned n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=(1<<31);i>0;i/=2)
        (i&n)?(cout<<1):(cout<<0);
}
```

I ran the following code with n=1 but it prints nothing on the console. Changing the type of variable i to unsigned did the trick and printed 00000000000000000000000000000001. Any idea why?

Comment: What is the number `0x80000000` of a signed 32 bit variable....?

Comment: And what is the end condition of the loop...?

Comment: [`i /= 2` and `i >>= 1` are not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10681375/995714)

Comment: Use `unsigned int i`.

Comment: As a side note: using ternary operator (?:) with statements seems weird.  It is more meant for expressions: `x = cond ? expr1: expr2;` so in your case `std::cout << (i&n? 1: 0);` or even better without the ternary operator: `std::cout << (i&n != 0);`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming two's complement, `1 << 31` results in a negative value, so your test for i > 0 fails immediately with the first test. You most likely would have had more luck with `i != 0` then.

But we aware that `1 << 31` is a signed integer overflow, which is undefined behaviour anyway! So you should do `1U << 31` instead, too. If you assign this then positive value to a signed int, which is not capable to hold it, you have again undefined behaviour. So the correct for loop would look like this:

```
for(unsigned int i = 1U << 31; i > 0; i /= 2)
```

Although `i /= 2` for unsigned values is equivalent to a bitshift (and is likely to be compiled to), I would prefere the bitshift operation explicitly here (`i >>= 1`), as this is what you actually intend.

Comment: Ahh I see.. Thanks a lot.. I did not notice the sign condition I myself put on my loop.. Thanks for pointing out the overflow bit! Will use     `1U << 31`

Answer (score 2):

Given that your platform is a 32-bit one, int i with a value of (i<<31) is a negative number. So, the execution never enters for-loop because you want i>0.

Comment: Yes I did not notice the error. It makes perfect sense. Thank you for pointing it out. Pretty silly a mistake.